# Django Channels: Data Going to the Wrong Socket

Tags: django, sockets, channel

I am facing the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870719/django-websockets-data-going-to-the-wrong-socket/65111245#65111245) although the as_asgi method is called in my routing. The data are always sent to the second socket.
Channels V3.0 and Django V3.1.2 is in use.

**routing.py**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(WS_PREFIX + r'room/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', RoomConsumer().as_asgi()),
]
```

**asgi.py**

```
import routing
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)

    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**Local server logs:**

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/room/2/ [127.0.0.1:63280]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/room/2/ [127.0.0.1:63280]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/room/1/ [127.0.0.1:63288]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/room/1/ [127.0.0.1:63288]
```

**consumer.py:**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class RoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'room_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        
        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send_data',
                'message': "Message received"
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def send_data(self, event):
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```

This is how I send data:

```
result['type'] = 'send_data'
result['test'] = 'test'
layer = get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(layer.group_send)('room_2', result)
return HttpResponse(status=202)
```

Is there anything else I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there is a newer version of channels available. I updated to channels V3.0.2 and it is working correctly now.